# I am needing help in Java for when I use an if statements for an OnClick method

Tags: java, android, if-statement, onclick

My code snip it is this. I am working on a sport scoring (baseball) app in Android. My code works for each button click so after one click with my strikes button the strike textview in my xml displays a 1. Then after a second click display 2. After a third click the strikes reset to 0 and my outs textview becomes a 1. Same for all the way for out 2.My problem is that when the strikes for the team equals 2 and my Outs for the team equals 2, on next button click the out's on my xml text view shows a 3. After another strike click the 3 resets back to a 0. While that is technically correct, I want it to when it displays a 2 strikes and 2 outs on next strike button click to reset the strikes and outs back to all zeros. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

```
 // Find the Button that shows the increment strike button for team A.
    final Button baseballAStrikePlus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.increment_a_strike);
    // Set a click listener on that View
    baseballAStrikePlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        // The code in this method will be executed when the category is clicked on.
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (teamAOuts == 3) {
                teamAOuts = 0;
                outsForTeamA(teamAOuts);
                return;

            } else {
                if (teamAStrikes == 2) {
                    teamAOuts = teamAOuts + 1;
                    outsForTeamA(teamAOuts);
                    teamAStrikes = 0;
                    strikesForTeamA(teamAStrikes);
                    return;
                }
            }
            teamAStrikes = teamAStrikes + 1;
            strikesForTeamA(teamAStrikes);
        }
    });
```

Comment: try a better explanation, this one is really messy plus you should use switch  or nested else if  for clarity

Comment: First time using stack exchange. My apologies.

Comment: no no nothing to apologize , that was just a advise . chill

Answer (score 0):

you may use AND to validate two conditions in if like :

```
 if (teamAStrikes == 2 && teamAOuts == 2) {
                teamAOuts = teamAOuts + 1;
                outsForTeamA(teamAOuts);
                teamAStrikes = 0;
                teamAStrikes = 0;
                strikesForTeamA(teamAStrikes);
                return;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a boundary condition.

With this `teamAOuts == 3` you are allowing `teamAOuts` to be 3 and then on next button click, you are making it 0.

What you need is, when `teamAOuts` and `teamAStrikes` both are 2, on the next button click, both become 0.

So replace this

```
if (teamAOuts == 3) {
       teamAOuts = 0;
       outsForTeamA(teamAOuts);
       return;
    }
```

with this

```
if (teamAOuts == 2 && teamAStrikes == 2) {
         teamAOuts = 0;
         outsForTeamA(teamAOuts);
         teamAStrikes = 0;
         strikesForTeamA(teamAStrikes);
         return;
  }
```